# Sign of the mass term in a Lagrangian

Tags: newtonian-gravity, lagrangian-formalism

The Lagrangian of Newtonian gravitation reads

$$
L=\frac1{8πG}(\partial φ)^2 + ρ\,φ
$$

where $\rho$ is the density of the gravitation source, i.e. the mass.

The Lagrangian is usually the difference between kinetic and potential energy: $L=T-V$. So $V = -\rho\varphi$ in Newtonian gravity.

But that means that the more mass the source $\rho$ has, the more negative is the potential energy.

How does this make sense? If the sun is heavier, then the earth surely has more potential energy.

Comment: Is this from a reference?

Answer (score 1):

The "potential" $V$ that you defined here is not the gravitational potential. In fact, under this Lagrangian formalism, $\varphi$ is the gravitational potential that you have in mind.

If you use the Euler-Lagrangian equation, you can recover the equation $4\pi G\rho=\nabla^2\varphi$, which is just Gauss' Law for gravity, which is an equivalent expression for $\varphi=-\frac{GM}{r}$.